# To pass value in DropDrownList to the Controller using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two textboxes and one dropdownlist. I have passed the value of textboxes to the controller action method using their id through Ajax.BeginForm() method. But how to pass value of dropdownlist as it has not defined by id. Here is my code:

DeliveryIndex.cshtml:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CustomerFilter", "Delivery", new System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "deliverylist"
 }))
{               
<input id="from" name="from" type="text" />

<input id="to" name="to" type="text" />

@Html.DropDownList("CUS_NAME",null,"--Select Customer--",new { @Style = "WIDTH:169PX" })

<input type="submit" value="View" id="BtnSubmit" />
}
```

Controller:

```
public class DeliveryController : MasterController
{
    public ActionResult DeliveryIndex()
    {      
        ViewBag.CUS_NAME = new SelectList(db.CUSTOMER_MASTER.ToList().OrderBy(c => c.CUS_NAME), "CUS_NAME", "CUS_NAME");
        return View("DeliveryIndex");      
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CustomerFilter(string from, string to, string )
    {     
    ....   
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you haven't bind it to a model. Use DropDownListFor and bind it to a model. You selected values will be available in your model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based upon your example the parameter should be available as `CUS_NAME`.

Changing your action to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CustomerFilter(string from, string to, string CUS_NAME)
{     
....   
}
```

Will pass it through, however I would advise using a strongly typed view model.

As an example:

**View Model**

```
public class FooViewModel
{
  public string From { get;set; }
  public string To { get;set; }
  // represents the selected value
  public string CusName { get;set; }
  public List<Customer> AvailableCustomers { get;set;}
}

public class Customer 
{
  public int Id { get;set;}
  public string Name { get;set;}
}
```

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CustomerFilter(FooViewModel model)
{     
 ....   
}
```

**View**

```
@model FooViewModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CustomerFilter", "Delivery", new System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "deliverylist"
 }))
{               
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.To)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CusName, new SelectList(model.AvailableCustomers, "Id", "Name"),"--Select Customer--",new { @Style = "WIDTH:169PX" })
   <input type="submit" value="View" id="BtnSubmit" />
}
```

**Update**
As per Stephen Muecke's comments, I have updated the model to include a list of options too.

Comment: This will not work - you need another property (say) `IEnumerable<SelectList> CusList` for the options (and then its `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CusName, Model.CusList, ....)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Very true, thanks. I'd add a selected value and options to the view model too. I'll update the answer when I get a chance.